# What is the distance between one of the mars's satellite revolving near the highest volcano olympus mons and the volcano olympus mons?

Tags: spacex, mars, nasa, orbit

Olympus mons is 27km high-more than three times the height of Mount Everest. 
Mars needs human landing so would we get a benefit if we landed on olympus mons as our first landing? Would the height be a noticable advantage?

Comment: What does the "m" stand for in "27m"?

Comment: @organic-marble i edited it to show actual height which is 27km

Comment: I don't understand where the question is here, the title and the question text do not match up.

Comment: Landing on Olympus Mons would be *very* hard. It's 27 km high so a parachute would not slow you down enough. Any landing on Olympus Mons from orbit would have to be almost entirely propellant based.

Comment: Related: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/6102/32284

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Olympus Mons - viable Mars landing site?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/6102/olympus-mons-viable-mars-landing-site)

Comment: Welcome to *Space!*  In future questions, please be more careful about your tags.  There's no reason to have `spacex` or `nasa` in this question.