# When things land on Mars what fraction of their velocity do they remove propulsively?

Tags: mars, orbital-maneuver, mission-design, lander, entry-descent-landing

Some recent comments have got me wondering about this

- [What is the distance between one of the mars's satellite revolving near the highest volcano olympus mons and the volcano olympus mons?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/43609/12102)
- comments and answers to its linked duplicate [Olympus Mons - viable Mars landing site?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/6102/12102) especially [this comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/6107/12102)

  > Sure, with enough rockets and propellant you could land there. However the mass required for all that propellant would vastly reduce the mass of your payload

Many things have landed on Mars. I'm not sure what fraction have entered orbit first versus direct deceleration from interplanetary trajectory to touch down.

In each case, what fraction of their velocity do they remove propulsively versus using atmospheric drag

I'm guessing it's 50% for interplanetary to landing and of order 10% for orbit to landing, but I could be way off.

Obviously answers will have to be rough since they may need to summarize several missions, and velocity increases once Mars' gravity kicks in.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Taking Mars Pathfinder and Viking 1 as examples:

Mars Pathfinder was a direct entry at 7600 m/s and removed about 0.7-0.8% of that propulsively. Parachute deployment was at 360-450 m/s, and landing rocket ignition at 52-64 m/s which slowed the vehicle to 0-25 m/s before cutting the bridle: https://mars.nasa.gov/MPF/mpf/edl/edl1.html

Viking 1 landed from orbit, removing about 5% of its velocity propulsively.  The deorbit burn was 180 m/s, entry velocity was 4580 m/s, aerodynamic braking was used down to 60 m/s, and from there it decelerated propulsively and touched down at 2.4 m/s: https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/nmc/spacecraft/display.action?id=1975-075C, https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19760018033.pdf

Comment: I'm surprised the aerodynamic braking velocities are that low.

Comment: To the question "... *what fraction* of their velocity do they remove propulsively?" can you explicitly mention some fractions? Thanks!

Comment: Of course, given the tiny size of the final landing burn compared to the velocity shed by aerobraking, a perfectly valid answer to @uhoh's question would be that they remove _all_ of their entry velocity by aerobraking — but then gain back some extra speed from falling under gravity, the last 60 m/s or so of which which they have to cancel using rockets because, even with a parachute, that's how high their terminal velocity on Mars is.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: That's true for these, but generally larger payloads will take more, since it becomes harder to keep the ballistic coefficient down. Red Dragon would have used an order of magnitude more propulsive delta-v, with no parachutes and its engines starting up while still supersonic, something NASA avoided due to lack of knowledge of how it'd perform.

Comment: I skipped the edit, @Klaycon , because, well, it's kinda right, but kinda wrong  -- but this may be because the question is "bad". The entry velocity is a very arbitrary figure, you don't include the speed shed that was gained after that point, at 3.7m/s/s (and no, I'm not the question downvoter)

Comment: @JCRM Sure, that makes sense. I really only have a vague grasp of factors that might play in to these numbers, I just found it remiss that among all the comments about how it's "such simple division" nobody had actually edited the answer. I'd gladly invite those with more insight to improve the answer with more sufficient numbers.

Comment: @Klaycon, The problem here is the OP was weak, in that it didn't explain how the fraction should be calculated (I'm not sure there is a meaningful way of expressing it as a fraction)

Comment: Russell, Christopher, and uhoh - Please give this one some space. Let's keep the dialog constructive here.